# can anyone explain difference between operators in this program int i=10;int n=i++%5;int k=++i%5;

Tags: java, unary-operator

Freebase query example in python:

I know that I'm dyslexic and I don't have a PhD but I always find Google `APIs` incomprehensible. I just need an example on the following: Get the `'/music/genre'` list and then get the `subgenres` ...

could anyone explain difference between operators in this program

```
int i=10;j=10;

int n=i++%5;

int k=++j%5;
```

when i try this program iam getting n=0 ,k=1 and i=11,j=11
and ++a and a++ operator with other operators.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Python? Musicgenres? Operators? What?

Comment: ^^------------- Agreed

Answer (score 2):

`i++` means "use the value of `i` *then* increment it"
`++i` means "increment the value of `i` *then* use it"
`i%5` means "the remainder after dividing `i` by `5`"

Answer (score 1):

`i++` and `++i` are called increments and both are equivalent to `i = i + 1` but differ in *when* the variable is incremented.

```
int i = 0;
System.out.println(i++); //This prints 0 then increments i to 1
System.out.println(++i); //This prints 2 because i is 
                         //incremented by 1 and then printed
```

`%` is the modulus operator and provides the remainder of a division problem.

```
6 % 4 = 2 //This is the same as saying 6 divided by 4,
          //but prints the remainder which is 2
```

For you specific problem:

```
int i=10;
int n=i++%5; //Here you have 10 % 5 which is 0, so n = 0.
             //After that i is incremented to 11.
```

Answer (score 0):

++ is called the increment operator, they increase the variable value by 1.

- When used in any expression, ++i will first increment the value of i by one and then use the incremented value in expression.
- On other hand when i++ is used in any expression, exp is evaluated with the initial value of i, and after that value of i is incremented by one.

`int n=i++%5;`
is equivalent to

```
int n=i%5; // i=10, n = 10%5 = 0;
i = i +1;  //i = 10 + 1 = 11
```

And `int k = ++j%5;`
is equivalent to

```
j = j + 1;      // j = 10 + 1 = 11 
int k = j % 5;  // k = 11 % 5 = 1
```

Hope this will be helpful.